# Plain progressive simple harmonic wave

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, wavefunction

We know the equation of a plain progressive simple harmonic wave going from left to right is,
$$y=a\sin\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(vt−x).$$
If we put $t=0$ and $x=0$, we get $y=0$;
and if we put $t=0$ and $x= 0.25 \lambda$,
we get $y=  a$

But How  could this be possible?
How could right side particles start oscillation
before the left ones? Don′t it need a
certain time gap for right side particles to start oscillating?

Comment: Which wave is this? what is "y"?

Comment: Any simple harmonic progressive wave

Comment: Lets say it's an electromagnetic wave. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: No i am not talking about EM waves..consider sound wave or waves in a string

Comment: what particles are you talking about? A [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) is a continuous wave, there is not particles involved in it. And how does $x=0.5\lambda$ give you $y=-a$, $y=\sin \pi = 0$! I don't understand this time gap you are talking about. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Sorry i edited something in the question i didn't know that my question changed automatically.I am talking about 12th class physics waves.. Where my textbook define sound wave or waves in a string by this sinusoidal equation

Comment: @MDHossain the density of particles and their velocity are both waves which are related: gradients in the velocity wave are the peaks of the density wave (in 3D divergence instead of gradient)

Comment: @MDHossain please note the density wave here http://resource.isvr.soton.ac.uk/spcg/tutorial/tutorial/Tutorial_files/longipatm.gif

Comment: In my textbook, this equation is written as a plain progressive wave equation. And sound wave is written as this format

Comment: This equation generates if all the particles in the wave oscillates  in simple harmonic motion. And the velocity of the wave is V.

Comment: @MDHossain There is velocity of the wave (which is traveling right and constant) and velocity of the particles, and they are different things. Notice a single red dot: its velocity is positive to the right, then it stops. then its velocity is negative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sinusoidal wave means that a sine wave profile has already established on the string. Probably, you are thinking about the initial stage of building up the wave by an oscillating drive in one end of the string (the transient period.) During the transient period, the wave on the string is not called a sinusoidal wave.

after the period, a sine wave is built on the string. At a fixed time (as $t=0$ of your choice), the profile of the string vertical displacement is a sine wave:
$$
   y(x, t=0) = a \sin k x.
$$
where $k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the wave number.

Comment: You mean,, this equation don't work when all the particles yet not start oscillating i.e. at the stage of starting the wave?

Comment: Yes. The equation is valid only after the wave is established.

Comment: ytlu - I thought when t=0 the wave will just start from this moment.What we actually mean by t=0??

Comment: The equation doesn't tell you when the wave was created. $t=0$ is arbitrarily established once the wave exists.

Comment: The starting time is only reflectiing  a choice of the arbitrary phase of the wave function $y(x,t) = a \sin \{ k(x - vt) + \phi \}$. It should not be interpreted as the wave initial  building time.

Comment: Thank you sir it was my first stack question.